# How to override css attribute-only style

Tags: css

I have a page that I need to modify some behavior. The element that I'm working on has a [attribute] directive, like this:

```
<div class="someClass" myAttributeDirective></div>
```

The `myAttributeDirective` has it's own css page that defines some styling, like this:

```
[myAttributeDirective] {
/* a few different properties */
border: 1px solid red;
position: relative;
}

/* then some more class stylings related to the directive */
```

So you see, in the css, it's defining some styles for JUST the attribute, so if the attribute exists in any element, apply those stylings.

When I view my element in Dev tools, it doesn't look quite right. In order to "fix" it, I un-check one of the css properties that is causing my issue, the `position: relative;`.

BUT

I can't change the "core" css for that directive, because it's used throughout the application. AND, if I try to override that property, it doesn't work (actually, cycling through the different position: * options only leads to making things look worse).

So, how do I override that specific property, without changing the core css file?

Comment: <offtopic>html attribute myAttributeDirective ? is that a valid html attribute?, maybe thats the reason why things are messed up?</offtopic>

Comment: create a new css file and maybe call it theme, add it after your core css and add rules to that atribute? in case it is not overriding correctly use !important

Comment: What about adding a new attribute directive after the `myAttributeDirective` to overwrite the previous one, and then place `!important` after the style you're trying to pass. The browser *should* overwrite the previously set styles with your new ones

Comment: Do you want to fix styling for only one specific element?

Comment: Instead of using `!important` (avoid `!important` whenever possible), just make your selector for this element a little more specific. `.someClass[myAttributeDirective]` will win against `[myAttributeDirective]` and only apply to the elements that also match `.someClass` (so your other things with `[myAttributeDirective]` are safe).

Comment: @ganders What is your actual problem? "Not quite right" is not a description. And *how* do you want it "fixed"?

Comment: @Mark it is an AngularJS directive, the attribute version

Comment: I removed that attribute altogether. Team found out that the directive is causing other issues inside our application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to override style in any case irrespective of which order style is applied, consider applying style inline in the div.

```
<div class="someClass" myAttributeDirective style="position:absolute;"></div>
```